# How to properly write http.get in Angular2?

Tags: angular, http

I wrote the http.get function in JS but I need it to be in Typescript for Angular2.

I think it involves map, but I don't know to return a function.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class UrlExists {

    constructor(
        public http: Http
    ) {
    }

      newF(url) {
            this.http
                .get(url)
                .success(function () {
                    return true;
                })
                .error(function () {
                    return false;
                });
        };

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest form would be:

```
newF(url) {
    return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json())                
};
```

This returns an `observable` type, which is not unlike a promise, like you've probably used, in that it CAN return a success or failure.  Observables are a lot more powerful than promises, but in a simple form, you'll get a response that is a success or a failure.

`Map` just transforms the object into a other object, ie the response and returns the JSON of the response.

That is without global error handling or anything.

You would use that in your component with:

```
myService.newF('some url').subscribe(
   data =>  //do something with data,
   error =>  //do something on error
);
```

For further reading on the HTTP client in Angular2, the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#) are pretty thorough.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to have a simple and clear answer. Thanks for your help.